# C++ lld-link error when access class A via pointer from class A_test

Tags: c++, linker

Now we have a class A, which has a struct C defined in its header file.

Class A's copy constructor and copy assignment operator must be deleted, because one of its class member has a deleted copy constructor, and deleted copy assignment operator.

Then we have a class ATest, which has a pointer to an instance of class A, and use this pointer to perform a series of validation task. Code is listed as below:

A.h

```
public:
  A();
  A(const A&) = delete;
  A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
  ~A() override;


  struct C{
     public:
      C(int id);
      C(const C& other);
      ~C();
      int id;
  };

  const std::vector<C>& GetC() const;

 Private:
  std::vector<C> c_;
```

A.cc

```
A::A() {
  // skip the implementation detail here
}
A::~A() = default;

const std::vector<A::C>& A::GetC() const {
  return c_;
}

A::C::C(int input_id)
    : id(input_id) {}
A::C::~C() = default;
A::C::C(const C& other) = default;
```

A_test.cc

```
#include "A.h"

// Test class definition and implementation.
class ATest {
 public:
  ATest() = default;
  ~ATest() = default;

  void SetUpTestEnv() {
    auto a = std::make_unique<A>();
    a_ = a.get();
  }

 private:
  A* a_;
}

// In test execution code:
SetUpTestEnv();
a_->GetC().size()    // lld-link: error: undefined symbol: public: class std::__1::vector<struct A::C, class std::__1::allocator<struct A::C>> const & __cdecl A::GetC(void) const
```

Overall we can see linking error as follows:

```
lld-link: error: undefined symbol: public: class std::__1::vector<struct A::C, class std::__1::allocator<struct A::C>> const & __cdecl A::GetC(void) const
lld-link: error: undefined symbol: public: __cdecl A::A(void)
lld-link: error: undefined symbol: public: virtual __cdecl A::~A(void)
```

I'm quite confused what is the reason for these linking error? A.h and A.cc is already added as dependency for A_test.cc during compilation. I really appreciate your suggestions and advices! Thanks!

Comment: You need ATest object to access a_

Comment: Show us your build system for compiling A_test.cc into an actual runnable program.

Comment: Fyi, `a_ = a.get();` - what do you suppose `a_` points to once `a` is destroyed upon exiting function `SetUpTestEnv` ? The object `a` pointed to is *gone* since the smart pointer that owned it is destroyed. In so doing, `a_` now holds a *dangling* pointer, and any dereference of it invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @WhozCraig actually we move the ownership of a to another object by
`std::make_unique<B>(nullptr, std::move(a), std::move(thread_b));`

Comment: That exists exactly *nowhere* in the posted code. You therefore understand my confusion, my remote-viewing skils have been on the fritz for years.

Comment: Thanks @Build Succeeded for the comments, the issue indeed lies in the BUILD.gn file, originally the A.cc and A.h was linked to A_test.cc as a deps, however due to some reason it was not working. Now with specifically adding A.cc to A_test.cc as a source, it is able to build successfully. It was still strange adding A.cc as a deps won't work tho.

Comment: @Botje thanks for your comments, the issue indeed lies in the BUILD.gn file, originally the A.cc and A.h was linked to A_test.cc as a deps, however due to some reason it was not working. Now with specifically adding A.cc to A_test.cc as a source, it is able to build successfully. It was still strange adding A.cc as a deps won't work tho.

Comment: @Skylar there might be other problem as well, need to find

Comment: Most build systems make a distinction between a dependency (A needs to be built before B) and an actual build input (A becomes part of B) Sounds like you were doing the former.